# OpenCv fails to find chessboard pattern on many of my images and Matlab not

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am doing GoPro camera calibration with OpenCv. But  findChessboardCorners return false on many of my images and Matlab not. I have tried to biniraze images to help OpenCv but it helps only in some cases. Here is example:

[image: Binirazed sample]

Here is code:

```
CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)
 img = cv2.imread('1.JPG') 
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE) 
 print(ret)
```

I have tried different flags. OpenCv fails and matlab not. Any hint?

Comment: You want to undistort the image before corner detection. Here is an article about it in python. https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by trying to find the chessboard pattern? Are you trying to obtain a bounding box around the entire board or trying to find the corners?

Comment: @nathancy findChessboardCorners return false

Comment: @Grebtsew  findChessboardCorners - return false, could not find chess-board corners

Comment: My guess is that when the function performs a threshold, it is not able to determine the border of the chessboard since the background and the "white" parts of the board are blended together

Comment: I agree with @nathancy, if you resize the image it will remove some of the blended pixels and you will get a little better results. So add :  
img = cv2.resize(img,(int(400),int(400)))

Comment: Without binarization on original images there is big difference between paper with this chessboard and background color and result is the same. On one of images such manual binarization helped openCv

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the image seems to work.

Code Sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)

img = cv2.imread("Q2l11.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img,(int(400),int(400)))


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
print(corners)
#print(ret)

corners = np.int0(corners)

for i in corners:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,(0,0,255),-1)

cv2.imshow('Corners',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:
[image: Result of detection]